# TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined at Object.Parse.File.save

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, sails.js

I use Sails Js for my project, and Parse.
The thing which doesn't work is that I can not upload a file to Parse.
There is a lot of same topic on the Internet, but always unsolved!

Everything works until this point :

```
var newFile = new Parse.File(fileName, file, contentType);
// fileName = blue.jpg, file = { JSON of all the file's information }, contentType = 'image/jpeg',
// newFile = { _name: 'blue.jpg' }
// so my HTML form works.

// I tried (1)
newFile.save().then(function() {
// The file has been saved to Parse.
}, function(error) {
// The file either could not be read, or could not be saved to Parse.
});

// I tried (2)
fs.readFile(filePath, function (err, data) {
    var newFile = new Parse.File('my_path_I_want...', data);
    newFile.save().then(function(file) {
    }, function(error) {
    });
});
```

And the problem is always the same :

```
myApp/node_modules/parse/build/parse-latest.js:4438
self._previousSave = self._source.then(function(base64, type) {
                                     ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined at Object.Parse.File.save      (myApp/node_modules/parse/build/parse-latest.js:4438:42)
```

I really don't know what to do/try now.

[Here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/parse-developers/F6t9HQYEBM8) they say it's a bug, but I don't believe, no upload since 2014..

And [here](https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#files-creating-a-parse-file) is the Parse documentation section for Parse File.

Have you got an idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally succeed with :

```
var fs = require('fs');
var fileData = fs.readFileSync(filePath);
fileData = Array.prototype.slice.call(new Buffer(fileData), 0)
var newFile = new Parse.File(fileName, fileData);
```

Parse wants an array of data, so I can understand why that works, but in the documentation, it's written we can do also with the way I posted at the beginning.
Maybe the "file" variable is not the same with sails js..

Answer (score 1):

Are you checking to see that the actual file exists?

```
ImageExist(url){
   var img = new Image();
   img.src = url;
   return img.height != 0;
}
```

Where your uploading it from, check that the path is not breaking as well.

Comment: The file exists. I even moved the file in another folder (it was before in .tmp/uploads/name_file, and now it's in assets/images/name_file) Still the same errors, exactly the same.